# Git scm on window server access rights

Tags: git

I am setting up a central Git repository in a window server. Just want to know if there is a way to do user access rights in git. For example: only Authorized user is able to pull , clone and push codes to the folder. Non Authorized user will be rejected. I've read about SSH configuration with the Git, but it doesn't prevent user from getting to another folder to clone codes. Any idea how to set user access for Git Repository?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For a Windows server you might look at [GitBucket](https://github.com/takezoe/gitbucket) which seems to be remarkably easy to setup on Windows. If I was not already using [GitLab](http://gitlab.org/) on a Linux server for providing git services to our Windows developers I would quite likely to try gitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a tool like [Atlassian Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash/overview).

An alternative would be to have an Apache HTTP Server as a proxy in front of your git. Then you can configure a location for each git repo. Something like:

```
<Location /test-repo.git>
    DAV on
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwd.git
    Require user user1 user2 user3
</Location>
```

With Apache all kinds of authentification is possible (Basic Auth, LDAP etc).

Comment: If i were to use HTTP server in front of git. When i do git clone.. it will hit ht access first?